# Google PubSub queue for distributed state management

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have *n* sources that a job depends on.
Each source has a separate topic in Google PubSub; when a source is updated it sends a message in the corresponding topic subscription. When **all** sources are updated (i.e. when there is at least one new message in each subscription) the job can start.
The job is scheduled with airflow. The DAG starts with a series of parallel tasks one for each subscription that check if a new message has been published, but without aknowledging it. The next task waits for all the previous ones and uses XCOM to see if **all** contains a message. In that case it proceeds with the job (it first aknowledge the messages), otherwise it stops.
In this way I acknowledge the messages only when they are all available, using PubSub as a *coordinator*. The messages frequency is once or twice a day at most.

Basically I'm using PubSub as way to keep "state". Suppose I have different jobs that depend on the same source. I can create a subscription for the same topic on each job and it all works fine.

Is there a better way/tool/framework to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with the volume of message that you have, and from my previous implementations, I can recommend you to persist states in Firestore: serverless, affordable, fast...

When a message is published, trigger a function that persist state in Firestore

Then, trigger the number of processes that you want, query Firestone to check if all the states are OK, and continue or stop.

It's my pattern for synchronization. Not that the best!

---

Anyway, if you create a subscription per process, it also works. The message are duplicated in each subscription and thus you can process them independently.

Comment: I have a prototype version that uses Firestore now. I have a document for each job, each with as many fields as datasources. When new data for a given source is available, a cloud function writes to every document that depends of that source. Then I check if any job has all sources available and fire the corresponding airflow DAG. I'm wondering however what happens if a new source arrives while I'm processing the existing one (I'm assuming message frequency will increase at some point). It is plausible to use Firestore for queuing as well? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: To answer you, I need to know better your data, what are the trigger conditions and so on. I recommend you to store the event and the date of the event. like this, you know when the latest event is arrived. Which event to exclude because they are too recent or too old. Without more info, I can't help you on the best data storage/format strategy!

Comment: The sources are csv files that are uploaded once a day to a cloud storage bucket. I have a cloud function that fires when a new csv is added and stores its path in Firestore. There are 4 different sources (i.e. files) that a job depends on. When all 4 are uploaded another Cloud function fires an Airflow DAG that uses dataflow to process the csv files. When the process is completed an operator "clears" the state by removing the paths in firestore's document for that job. Hope this clarify a little bit! Thanks!